# 'System.AggregateException' occurred while trying to use Google Analytics in Windows store app 8.1

Tags: c#, google-analytics, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, measurement-protocol

I am trying to use Google Analytics in my windows store app but I am getting an exception. I am totally new to this stuff. Please help me fix this.

NuGet Package: GoogleAnalyticsSDK

Exception:

```
 `System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional
      (BooleanincludeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait
      (Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
       at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.InitConfig(Uri configPath)
       at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.SetContext(Application ctx)
       at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker()
       at HelloWorld.MainPage..ctor()
       at    HelloWorld.HelloWorld_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()
       at HelloWorld.HelloWorld_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException: System.Xml.XmlException
       HResult=-2146232000
       Message='Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 33, position 29.
       Source=System.Xml
       LineNumber=33
       LinePosition=29
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
            at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTrackerConfig.LoadConfigXml(XmlReader reader)
            at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTrackerConfig.Load(XmlReader reader)
            at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.InitConfig(XmlReader reader)
            at GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.<InitConfig>b__0(Task`1 t)
            at `System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask1.InnerInvoke()`
               ` at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
       InnerException:{"'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 33, position 29."}`
```

Here is the C# code in which I am using the analytics.Which has 3 buttons on the main page and I am just checking to see if the app is reporting the statistics using the google analytics platform.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace HelloWorld
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            string a = "Main";
             GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView(a);

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("Button1");

        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("Button2");
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("Button3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you running the code.. or did you actually use the debugger to step through the code..?

Comment: You might want to try and contact the owner of that third party sdk for windows.   But it looks like he hasn't developed on it since 2015.  AggregateException  sounds like an error in the library itself.  Note: There is no official Google-Analytics-sdk for windows.

Comment: Yes I am running the Code on emulator. @MethodMan

Comment: Oh I see. Then what would be the best option for analytics in a windows store app. Which is official kind of. Thank in advance @DalmTo